Unclear why useSuspenseQuery would fire on the server without an explicit prefetch
Tanstack Query docs state:

If you do forget to prefetch a query when you are using useSuspenseQuery, the consequences will depend on the framework you are using. In some cases, the data will Suspend and get fetched on the server but never be hydrated to the client

I understand that SSR involves generating an initial HTML view and sending that to the client, but why (and how) would useSuspenseQuery even run a fetch on the server if there wasn't an explicit .prefetch call in a React server component? (Referring to the Next JS App router specifically, but perhaps this applies to other frameworks as well)
